# How to get the first revision number of a particular day in SVN

Tags: svn

The requirement is for one of the Continuous Integration project where I need to take nightly build.

I need Sub version command that can give first revision number of that day.

I tried the below command, but it was of no use:

svn log  -r {2013-09-30}:{2013-09-30} | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2

Hope i am clear about the requirement. Please do guide...

Thanks,
-Rajiv

Comment: No tostao, this is not what i am asking for...i just need the first revision number of a particular day.The answer that you are pointing to has the file details for the revision number that we pass. say there are 10 revision that checked-in today, i just need the first revision number for today...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 svn -q log | grep <DATE> | tail -n1 | cut -d'|' -f1
```

E.g.,

```
svn -q log | grep 2013-09-30 | tail -n1 | cut -d'|' -f1
```